# Child class listening to static parent method

Tags: php, static-methods

I'm pretty sure my question has been answered somewhere but it seems I can't find an answer, so here I try.

Is there a way for a child class to listen to a static method of its parent class and execute one of its static methods ? Or should it use an interface, and if so, how would you do it ?

The best example is with the Command class : you have that :

```
class Command {
    public static function execute($name, $args) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

And when you call that method execute, all subclasses see if name corresponds to their name.

```
class Subcommand extends Command {
    public static $name = "command";

    public static function execute($name, $args) {
        if (self::$name === $name) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is there must be multiple classes such as Subcommand and I don't want to manually call all of them, there should be something to do that automatically.

For now, I've just put an array in the Command class like that :

```
$commands = [
    Subcommand1::class,
    Subcommand2::class,
    Subcommand3::class
    // …
]
```

And I iterate over it and call the execute method of each subclass but I was hoping there could be something more elegant to achieve that.

Comment: When you say _"child class"_, do you mean subclass? As in, an extending class?

Comment: I don&#39;t know the English name haha, when you use extends, yeah

Comment: That's ok, just wanted to clarify your question. Can you show some examples of what you'd like to achieve and explain what problems your having?

Comment: I edited the post, is it better ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think that your current approach is the elegant one (look at the [Command](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command) design pattern).

As I understand, what you are trying to achieve is to execute a method of all registered subclasses of `Command`. This is **not elegant at least by two points**. **Firstly**, you have to filter out your subclasses from all declared classes (using [`get_declared_classes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php)). This can be pretty exhaustive. **Secondly**, in such case, you can control the number of commands to be executed only by adding or removing them classes. This actually defeats the purpose of OOP (**Object**-Oriented Programming, not Class-Oriented Programming). The flow of your program should be defined by the interaction of object.

Comment: I see, thanks for your answer, it's very clear. I'll go with my current approach then.

Answer (score 0):

The `$name` parameter to `execute()` feels like it needs examining here:

- What are its valid values? (Is it completely free-form, or selected from some enum?)
- How do they relate to sub-commands? (1-to-1? 1-to-many? many-to-many?)
- How does the caller choose it?

I'd be tempted to say that the caller of `execute()` shouldn't be passing in that information; if it knows which command to use, it should be constructing an object representing that command.

If each name corresponds 1-to-1 to a sub-command, then the caller can just instantiate the sub-command class. If it's a 1-to-many or many-to-many relationship, you would need some additional "command type" classes; or you could construct the same object each time, but with a list of sub-commands it should dispatch to.

You might also want a factory method which is given the name of the command, and constructs an appropriate sub-command or command type. That allows the choice of command to be dynamic, e.g. from user input, and keeps any complex the logic about what object to create in one place. That could be a hard-coded switch statement where you manage all the name-to-class relationships, or it could be a registry, where new sub-classes can register for particular command names.

The last case is essentially the Observer pattern: the command names are events, and the sub-classes have registered to observe them. As `sevavietl` this makes the relationships more explicit: the existence of a class shouldn't normally trigger behaviour if that class isn't actually listed anywhere. This is particularly true in PHP, where classes are generally only looked up on disk when they are first referenced, so you don't actually know at run-time how many classes your project contains.

Comment: The $name is totally free-form, the subclasses just check if it corresponds to their name and execute themselves depending on that.

I wanted to do it like that to avoid having 20-30 if statements in case I have 20-30 different commands. I think I'll read your message again, as it has a lot of useful information, and if it ends up as "this is not how I should do it", I will take in consideration all other ways to do that.

Thanks for the time spent answering me ! :D

Comment: @Coqéliko That sounds very like an observer pattern to me - the values of `$name` are arbitrary events, and the classes register themselves for certain events. Then you can just maintain a mapping in an associative array of events to observers, e.g. `[ 'foo' => [ $instanceOfFooHandler, $instanceOfEverythingHandler ], 'bar' => [ $instanceOfBarHander, $instanceOfEverythingHandler ] ]`. Then you don't need any if statements, and the only time you loop through all the subclasses is when you register them for events in some kind of bootstrapping code.